# where we need to write code for "To detect language change in device"

Tags: android

Where we need to write code for "To detect language change in device"

I mean `Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();`" part is better to write in `onCretae();` or `onResume()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in onResume() if you want to check the language every time your application comes to the foreground.

Answer (score 2):

you can put it in onCreate(); it's not going to change.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to write in the **onCreate()** method itself than the onResume()

Comment: I am using a app in EN lang in mid i minimized the app and changed the lang to FR and opened the minimized app then what will happen?

Answer (score 0):

Its better to write in the **onResume**() method itself than the *onCreate*()